# PDO Error when using single quotes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I've been looking for the answer to this problem for ages and cannot find a solution.

The error is:

```
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

and of course I know what this error means, but I don't understand why it's actually throwing it only when I surround something in single quotes.

Here's my code:

```
$query = "UPDATE $DbTableName SET name=':name' WHERE id=:Id";
$result = $dbc->prepare($query); //Prepare query

$values = array('Id' => $Id, 'name' => $name); //Prepare values
$result->execute($values); //Execute Query
```

see the single quotes around :name

If I remove these quotes then there's no PDO error, but a MySQL error because a string needs to be surrounded by single quotes..

How can I get around this?

MySQL error when setting name to bob without quotes:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'bob' in 'field list'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't put quotes around statement parameters. What is the MySQL error?

Comment: It's hardly possible. I'd say that you have shown us not the **exact** code.

Comment: Actually, that is the exact code. Just because you believe it to be improbable does not mean it is impossible. I have accepted an answer that has fixed this for me. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that the `param` is indeed a string, using an example from the PHP manual:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(2, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Technically I believe `execute` makes a best guess judgement on the type of, but by using `bindParam` or `bindValue` you can explicitly state the type.

Comment: would this work then? $result->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR)

Comment: Hi - yes, using the example from above, to use named placeholders you could do this: `$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Answer (score 0):

This is completely rewritten answer. I was fooled at first by the reasoning in the other answer and didn't pay the proper attention to the question itself.

So here goes the simple answer:

> I don't understand why it's actually throwing it only when I surround something in single quotes.

Because you cannot use placeholders inside strings. A placeholder could represent a complete data literal only.

Comment: Actually I was not confused about strings at all. Downvoted for not reading my question properly

Comment: (Post Answering Party's Edit) Actually it was causing a PDO error with the quotes, and causing a MySQL error without them, I have already accepted an answer, which was way more helpful than your removing of my single quotes, which if you read my question properly, I already mentioned did not work. Thank you for trying to answer my question, but my down-vote stands.

Comment: I have accepted an answer, and it is the CORRECT answer. If you object to this, then by all means please do, but do not accuse me of having typos in my code. I tried your solution and it failed. the answer I accepted did not fail, therefore yours is wrong. Your code may work for most circumstances, but not this one. Accept it and move on